# Apex - Check if user has permission to edit Field

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript, controller

Is there a way to check via Apex or Javascript (Lightning Component JS Controller) if current user has permission (profile or Permission set) to **Edit** fields on Account Object ? For example, i have a lightning component and i would like to make Account fields that user does not have write access, read only. And fields that current user has access to make them editable.
Any suggestions please ?

Comment: You may just like to use [`lightning:recordEditForm`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:recordEditForm/documentation) in this case to build your custom component which takes care of field level security.

Comment: Thanks, Jayant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Salesforce does provide a mechanism in Apex to check the FLS for field for the current running user:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_perms_enforcing.htm

There is also the FieldPermission SObject as well you can query against:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_fieldpermissions.htm

Comment: Bryan, thank you very much for your response.